# Is there anything equivalent to Kotlin's `internal` visibility modifier in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Kotlin has `internal` visibility scope which makes a class visible only inside its module, is there anything like that in Flutter? Sort of like underscore for a specific module.

I know that package's code is already private, but there are certain things I would like to expose, some wouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. Take a look at the http package: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/tree/master/pkgs/http/lib
Public things are exposed in lib directory, when internal stuff is in lib/src. If you imported something from lib/src you would get a warning from analyzer.

Comment: How did they achieve to throw a warning from analyzer?

Comment: They don't, dart analyzer recognizes if files are being imported from src directory.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/tree/master/lib seems like it's removed from the repository. Can you share the example or the updated link?

Comment: @SnehalSingh sure, done, but it's nothing special, every dart package looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

Dart has no concept like a module or visibility within that module. Darts concept only consits of libraries und the visibility modifier "_" (underscore), which means "private to it's library".

A (micro) library in Dart consists of one single file. So you could place classes, top level functions, global variables, etc. within that file and name them starting with "_", to keep them private. Everything that's public should not start with an underscore.

If you're planning to release your own lib on pub.dev, go and check out the Dart documentation about pub packages and libraries (https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages). It explains how to export public API and keep your internal stuff away from the outside world.